# Switching a prefix for a command in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

First post on this site so my bad if I don't format something correctly. I've been trying to make a change prefix command and I don't know how to check next message content for a variable to use instead of the old prefix.

```
msg.reply("Which prefix do you want?");
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(msg.channel, m => m.author.id === msg.author.id, { time: 5000 });
        console.log(collector)
        collector.on('collect', msg => {
            newprefix=collector.content();
          msg.reply('Prefix succesfully changed!');
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly advise using the awaitMessages method.  First you need to define a filter, a delegate function that returns true if the reaction is one you want.  Typically in a command/response setting, you want a filter that indicates the original command invoker replied.

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return user.id === msg.author.id;
};
```

You can then define options for your awaitMessages. (It's quite common to do this in-line with the awaitMessages method, that's fine if that is more clear to you)

```js
const options = { 
    max: 1, 
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time'] 
}
```

The above example accepts 1 message, if given in 30 seconds, otherwise it throws an exception.

Finally, you are ready to begin...

```js
msg.reply("Which prefix do you want?").then(() => {
    msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
        .then(collected => {
            newprefix = collected.first();
            // Record newprefix to a persistent config here
            msg.reply('Prefix successfully changed!');
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            msg.reply("You didn't respond fast enough.");
        });
}
```

Keep in mind, this occurs asynchronously, so if you need to write newprefix somewhere, a JSON config file for example, you should do from within the scope of the `.then`